# Paypal button not showing in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to add a paypal button in my react.js project. I follow the instructions on https://github.com/thinhvo0108/react-paypal-express-checkout.

My code is:

```
import PaypalExpressBtn from "react-paypal-express-checkout";

class PaymentListing extends Component {
 render() {
   const client = {
    sandbox:
      "sandbox id",
    production: "YOUR-PRODUCTION-APP-ID"
  };
 return (
 <PaypalExpressBtn
        client={client}
        env={"sandbox"}
        currency={"USD"}
        total={1.0}
      />
 )
 }
 }
```

and i get this error too:

[image]

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: Looks like its a problem within the Paypal component and not yours.

Comment: Then what should i do? How can i integrate paypal with my reactjs project?

Comment: I'd search for another library. Something that looks more alive (: